# Python file content replacement for CSS properties

Tags: python, html, css, python-3.x

So I have 2 files: `config.txt` and a CSS file.

What I want to do is to read from the config file the color attribute and replace it on the CSS file.

Config file:

```css
color: #ffffff;
```

CSS file:

```css
body{ color: #000000;} h1{color:#000000;}
```

What I need to do is replace the CSS file `color` with the config file `color`, how can I do this using Python file operations replacing only the `color` of the `h1` tag and not the `body` tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) module for in-place file editing and the [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) regex module for doing search-and-replace on that specific `h1` tag.

Here's the code first:
(Note that I used "config.txt" for the config file and "output.css" for the CSS file)

```py
# read the color from the config file
color_config = ""
with open("config.txt", "r") as config_file:
    for line in config_file:
        if line.startswith("color"):
            color_config = "h1 {" + line.strip() + "}"
            break

# update the css file in-place
with fileinput.input(files=("output.css"), inplace=True) as css_file:
    for line in css_file:
        # the h1 tag could be on its own line or could be part of
        # a line with other styles, so we capture them in groups
        matches = re.match(r"(.*)(h1\s*\{color:.*\})(.*)", line)
        if matches:
            # group(0): entire matching line
            # group(1): everything before the h1 tag
            # group(2): the h1 tag
            # group(3): everything after the h1 tag
            print(line.replace(matches.group(2), color_config), end="")
        else:
            print(line, end="")
```

For some explanation:

- The first `with` block is where we read the config file to get the `color: #ffffff;` value. I am assuming here that it's placed on its own line (that's why I used `startswith`). I don't know what your config file looks like, so just tweak it based on what you need.
- Then, we store `color: #ffffff;` into `color_config`, formatted as an `h1 { .. }` string. We format it now to make it easy to search and replace later.
- The second `with` block does the in-place file search-and-replace. It uses [`fileinput.input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input) with the `inplace` parameter set to `True`. From the docs:

> **Optional in-place filtering**: if the keyword argument `inplace=True` is
>   passed to `fileinput.input()` or to the `FileInput` constructor, the file
>   is moved to a backup file and standard output is directed to the input
>   file (if a file of the same name as the backup file already exists, it
>   will be replaced silently). This makes it possible to write a filter
>   that rewrites its input file in place. If the *backup* parameter is
>   given (typically as `backup='.<some extension>'`), it specifies the
>   extension for the backup file, and the backup file remains around; by
>   default, the extension is `'.bak'` and it is deleted when the output
>   file is closed.

- In this second `with` block, we read each line of the CSS file, replace parts of the string, then `print` it back to the same file (`fileinput` redirects the `print` output to the file). It's best that the CSS file is not opened anywhere else when doing the in-place file editing.
- Next step is to search for the `h1` tag from each line. We do this with [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match). I won't go into the *long* explanation on how to use regex (you'll have to read that on your own). I'll just describe the pattern used:

> `re.match(r"(.*)(h1\s*\{color:.*\})(.*)", line)`
>
> `(.*)     match and group everything before and after the`h1`tag`
>   `\s*      match 0 or more spaces between h1 and {`
>   `\{, \}   match the brackets (escaped, because {} are regex special chars)`
>   `color:.* match any number of characters between color: and }`

- As described in the code comments, we can then get the `h1` tag by using [`match.group`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.group).
- The last step is to do the actual [string replacement](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) using the `color_config` read earlier and then printing it out to the file. Note that I optionally passed a `end=""` to `print`, because by default `print` outputs include a newline. Again, I don't know what your CSS file looks like, so tweak as needed.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer @Gino Mempin!
Do you think I could use this approach for a SASS file instead?
What about if the css file was formated as such?

h1{
    color:#000000;
    font-family: 'Verdana', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
} (in a collumn as it does not display as a column in the comment box :\)

Comment: To be more clear, when I get a more complex CSS file I will only want to replace the "color: xxxxxx;" part and not the whole h1 tag. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: @Maia Depending on your CSS/SASS file/format, you don't need to capture the entire `h1` tag, just the line with the `color`, something like just "`color:.*;`. I suggest you read about **[How to Use Regex](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/regex.html)**. It's a very useful skill.

Comment: @Maia Since you'll be parsing the file line-by-line, you can either (1) look for lines with the specific start tags first (ex. "`h1 {`") then apply the regex matching and replace up to the closing "`}`" tag, or (2) you could collect all the multi-lines in between `{..}` first, apply regex matching, then replace the block in one go.